# How to pass a javascript global variable into requirejs, ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, requirejs, recurly

I am implemented Recurly payments into a project, the project is using requirejs and there are requirejs 2 javascript files, 1 named 'front.js.coffee' for customer facing site and the second named 'admin.js.coffee' for the CMS. I have created a global variable as a partial that I render into the website header and then I need the front.js file to pull this value in order to build the Recurly transaction form. I had to do it this way because I need the server to generate a signature so therefore this had to pass through a '*html.erb' file.

So here is the global variable inside a shared view file:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
   signature_value: '<%= j RECURLY_SIGNATURE %>'
<% end %>
```

So here is the JS inside the front.js file:

```
Recurly.config
 subdomain: 'iewebinar'
 currency: 'USD'
 country: 'US'
Recurly.buildTransactionForm
 target: '#recurly-transaction'
 successURL: '/webinars/thank_you.html'
 signature: 'signature_value'
```

I am new to Ruby on Rails development and I dont entirely understand Requirejs so simple instructions would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

before you requiring the js files, you can add

```
<script>
  window.signature_value = '<%= j RECURLY_SIGNATURE %>'
</script>
```

then just use `window.signature_value` in your config.

```
successURL: '/webinars/thank_you.html'
signature: window.signature_value
```

one more option is to change the filename to `admin.js.coffee.erb`.  This will give you access to ruby functions so you <strike>**may**</strike> have access to the constant <strike>(sorry i'm not sure about this).</strike>

```
successURL: '/webinars/thank_you.html'
signature: '<%= RECURLY_SIGNATURE %>'
```